# \sqsubset without topline and bottomline

Tags: symbols

How may one define a symbol as `\sqsubset` but without the top line, and another symbol as `\sqsubset` but without the bottom line?

Edit 1:

At this point I use `\[x\bm{\sqsubset} y\longeq x \ \raisebox{-0.1pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{L}} \ y\wedge x \ \raisebox{-2pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\reflectbox{L}}} \ y\]` , under graphicx and bm, and amsmath etc.

The problem is to have  `\raisebox{-0.1pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{L}}` and `\raisebox{-2pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\reflectbox{L}}}` as similar as possible to `\bm{\sqsubset}`.

The solution I have may be satisfactory, but it is not optimal.

Comment: Your question could be much improved with a small test document which shows which package you use for `\sqsubset` and a sketch how the result should look like.

Comment: It looks like a job for the `pigpen` package.

Comment: @egreg I would appreciate a better solution than I gave.

Comment: @Sapiens Not without more details about your needs.

Comment: @egreg See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l__sapiens_wd_dim
\dim_new:N \l__sapiens_ht_dim
\dim_new:N \l__sapiens_dp_dim
\dim_new:N \l__sapiens_tot_dim
\box_new:N \l__sapiens_base_box

\NewDocumentCommand{\genericsq}{m}
 {
  \mathrel{ \mathpalette \__sapiens_sq:nn { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__sapiens_sq:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { $\use:c{m@th}#1\sqsubset$ }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__sapiens_wd_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__sapiens_ht_dim { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__sapiens_dp_dim { \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__sapiens_tot_dim { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box + \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__sapiens_base_box
   {
     {
      \draw_begin:
      \draw_linewidth:n { 0.05\l__sapiens_wd_dim }
      \draw_cap_round:
      \draw_join_round:
      \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.1\l__sapiens_wd_dim , \l__sapiens_tot_dim - 0.04\l__sapiens_wd_dim }
      \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.1\l__sapiens_wd_dim , 0.025\l__sapiens_wd_dim }
      \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.9\l__sapiens_wd_dim , 0.025\l__sapiens_wd_dim }
      \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
      \draw_end:
     }
   }
  \__sapiens_print:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__sapiens_print:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {lb}{}
    {lt}
     {
      \box_scale:Nnn \l__sapiens_base_box { 1 } { -1 }
      \hbox_set:Nn \l__sapiens_base_box
       {
        \box_move_up:nn { \l__sapiens_tot_dim } { \box_use:N \l__sapiens_base_box }
       }
     }
    {rb}
     {
      \box_scale:Nnn \l__sapiens_base_box { -1 } { 1 }
     }
    {rt}
     {
      \box_scale:Nnn \l__sapiens_base_box { -1 } { -1 }
      \hbox_set:Nn \l__sapiens_base_box
       {
        \box_move_up:nn { \l__sapiens_tot_dim } { \box_use:N \l__sapiens_base_box }
       }
     }
   }
  \box_move_down:nn { \l__sapiens_dp_dim } { \box_use:N \l__sapiens_base_box }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\bsqsubset}{}{\genericsq{lb}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tsqsubset}{}{\genericsq{lt}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bsqsupset}{}{\genericsq{rb}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tsqsupset}{}{\genericsq{rt}}


\begin{document}

$ A \sqsubset B \bsqsubset C \tsqsubset D \bsqsupset E \tsqsupset F$

$ \sqsubset\bsqsubset \scriptstyle\sqsubset\bsqsubset $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! In my context, sqsubset sits slightly below bsqsubset and tsqsubset, and raisebox does not resolve it in a stable manner. Is there a way to define a substitutesqsubset on a par with bsqsubset and tsqsubset, in the same vein?

Comment: @Sapiens I can't know your context.

Comment: Is there a way to raise/lower bsqsubset and tsqsubset?

Comment: @Sapiens You asked about symbols that are the same as sqsubset, but without one of the horizontal bars. That’s what I provided. You’ve been on the site for quite some time and I expect you to know how to ask questions.

Comment: You are right. But the question was on "how to define a symbol as \sqsubset but without ...", or, as you put it, "the same as sqsubset, but without one of the horizontal bars".  The expressions "as sqsubset" and "the same as sqsubset" are important here. Anyway, I am very grateful for your reply, which is very satisfactory, even though it, as it appears to me, is not a solution such that none more satisfactory can be imagined. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

$
\lefthalfcup
\lefthalfcap
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I use 36 packages, and my understanding is that MnSymbol does not combine well with them.

Comment: @Sapiens You are not showing a single package in your question. If you have such difficult constrains, you really should put more effort in your questions. You have been asked so many times to include a MWE in your questions.

Comment: I don't understand what an MWE could be here. This is half of what I want: $\rotatebox{270}{L}$.

Comment: @Sapiens A MWE would serve multiple purposes: a) it would safe users willing to help you from having to come up with all the boring stuff like a class and a document environment and b) it would allow users to come up with a solution which works for your circumstances.

Comment: In addition, I will use $\rotatebox{270}{\reflectbox{L}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score -2):

Use \raisebox{-0.1pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{L}}and \raisebox{-2pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\reflectbox{L}}} under the graphicx package.